# Vaadin 11 - how to set productionMode in application.yml

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10

I have been trying many solutions:

```
app.vaadin.productionMode: "true"
app.vaadin.productionMode: true
vaadin.servlet.productionMode: true
```

But nothing is working, I always get this msg in console:

```
===========================================================
Vaadin is running in DEBUG MODE.
Add productionMode=true to web.xml to disable debug features.
===========================================================
```

What is the good way of going production mode with spring boot (in a yml file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct property name, which enables production mode on Vaadin 10 (and 11):

```
vaadin.productionMode: true
```